Can I clone an iPod Nano 5th gen to an iPod Classic 5.5?
I got myself a nice iPod Classic 5.5 (Don't know why though, I have a perfectly working iPod Nano 5th gen).
I want to duplicate everything on my Nano to my Classic so that means not just the music but includes the playlists too (and metadata).
Is this posibble and secondly is there a (simple) way to achieve this?
I read something about simply cloning the data to the new device but that was from one classic 5.5 to another. Would that work too for nano 5th gen to classic 5.5?

Can‘t you just sync the nano to your Mac and then use this to sync to the classic?

I have a lot of music that doesn't come from Apple and is not in my iTunes library. I don't know if that would work (I don't have a Mac but use Windows). I was hoping I could connect both at the same time and do some sort of clone operation.

How are you getting the tracks onto the Nano currently? Assume this is iTunes/Music on Windows, can’t you just sync the same tracks onto the classic?

I’ve had great luck with iMazing to bring music back from a device to a computer so you don’t have to attempt this twice as hard operation.

@nohillside yes, I use iTunes on my windows computer.

If you have iTunes already, why can’t you sync the same tracks etc to both iPods?
